# How to read data from RAM?

Tags: windows, memory

I know this is a vague question. Please accept my apology but I'm trying to get an answer for this question.

I wanted to know if there's a way to current data from RAM? For example:- I have an In-Memory application running and I wanted to know what data set does it hold. Any pointers on this would be great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this link may be help you https://superuser.com/questions/226961/how-do-people-recover-data-from-ram

Comment: I seem to remember from *years* ago you could use a modded DD varient to dump the contents of a running windows install. This forensics wiki page might be a [start](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Tools:Memory_Imaging)

Answer (score 2):

Set the computer to hibernate and boot it up with a livecd or liveusb. Afair the pagefile.sys and hiberfil.sys are built up from 4k pages, and will contain the memory used by your apps and windows. You can look at both binwalk and volatility. I can't really tell you what goes where, and why. It has always seemed very random. I can only find the bits of memory I want by putting something like longuniquestring in the program's memory (but this is not the right way Im sure). Alternatively you can just attach a debugger to your program (ida), but Ive only used gdb. Look for some ida guides. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

In modern operating systems, RAM accesses are separated between processes. Therefore you cannot build a simple application to take a look into the data of another progam running. To do this you will have to program in kernel mode or use debug functions of the specific operating system.

Comment: Thank you for the input. In this example - I'm looking at Windows as an example. What skills do I need to debug or write program in kernal mode? Can I use some low level language like C++ to view the data? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @user400336 - Pointers are the closest thing you can get to the hardware.

Comment: The Debugging Application Programming Interface may be a good place to start http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809754.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You tagged Windows, yes it's possible (at least in the general case of a user on their own computer with admin rights).

A lot of game cheat engines (I won't link any as I'm not 100% sure which are safe, but I have used one for research) will let you search the memory of a running process for a given value, or browse through it. These values can then be changed, or 'locked' which I think is simply done by having the program repeatedly write the required value very quickly to undo any changes.

Comment: The one called literally "Cheat Engine" works quite well and until now hasn't been _unloyal_ to its users.

Answer (score 0):

For older Windows it used to be possible for a program to read or copy or search through RAM (probably excluding special kernel marked "secret" areas).

Once I used such a program in WinXP (maybe even an older one) to find hours of work that were almost lost when a program crashed before saving to disk. Was able to search through ram, find the unwritten data still waiting there, copy it and vow to **ALWAYS SAVE TO DISK OFTEN** in the future.

I'm not sure about current Windows versions, I'd think it's possible somehow, especially if not looking in protected / secure ram, if you're the superuser / root. There should still be a program available to search ram, somewhere.

---

[FYI, just read about a neat linux feature in `/dev/mem` that appears to be a direct link to easily read ram, but it doesn't seem to be what it looks like; doesn't super easily search for words/strings, and causes log entires like "`Program strings tried to access /dev/mem between 100000->101000."]

Answer (score 0):

You use a debugger, like the one in Microsoft Visual Studio.  You can attach to the process and have a look around at its memory, what threads it is executing, and the assembly instructions they are executing.